# UILabel moving into the view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Does anyone know how I can move inside the view of a Label created programmatically (i.e. move it to point (200,200). Here is the code for creating it.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
myLabel.text=@"Beppe";
myLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor grayColor];
myLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will move the labels center to (200,200), pretty standard stuff

```
myLabel.center=CGPointMake(200, 200)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
myLabel.text=@"Beppe";
myLabel.center=CGPointMake(200, 200);
myLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor grayColor];
myLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```